# Перебор и удаление дублей массива

Tags: php, массивы

Существует вот такой массив:

[1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Vitaliy
            [1] => 093565491
            [2] => fa4щnt1eby1@gmail.com
        )

```
[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => Vitaliy
        [1] => 093565491
        [2] => fa4щnt1eby1@gmail.com
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => test test
        [1] => tets
        [2] => test@test.com
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => test test
        [1] => tets
        [2] => test@test.com
```

Как удалить в нем дубли? Использовал стандарные функции по типу array_unique и т.п. но не выходит.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/946300/10293647

Comment: Уникальность искать нужно только по одному полю или нескольких? Первый комментарий на сайте и уже то, что Вам нужно - http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-unique.php

Comment: спасибо большое!

Answer (score -2):

```
$a=[1,2,5,8,1,2,4,5,7,6,9,4];
    $b=[];
for($i=0;$i<count($a);$i++){
$b[$a[$i]]=$a[$i];
}
print_r($b);
```

вот так без какой либо стандарт function array_unique

Comment: А если ассоциативный массив? А если значения(`$a[4]` к примеру) является функцией или объектом?

Comment: если ассоциативный массив то лутше зделать ето  с помощью foreach место for

Comment: можеш пробовать ету  на php online